# How do you listen for changes in a Firestore collection based on a query?

Tags: objective-c, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How do you listen for changes in a Firestore collection if a document is added or deleted that matches a query? This is for an iOS app in Objective-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`addSnapshotListener`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/FIRQuery#-addsnapshotlistener:) on your [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/FIRQuery):

```
[[[self.db collectionWithPath:@"cities"] queryWhereField:@"state" isEqualTo:@"CA"]
    addSnapshotListener:^(FIRQuerySnapshot *snapshot, NSError *error) {
      if (snapshot == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error fetching documents: %@", error);
        return;
      }
      NSMutableArray *cities = [NSMutableArray array];
      for (FIRDocumentSnapshot *document in snapshot.documents) {
        [cities addObject:document.data[@"name"]];
      }
      NSLog(@"Current cities in CA: %@", cities);
    }];
```

This listener will to documents where state field is CA. You can read more about this in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection)